# Transfer files from windows 2008 to win7

Tags: file-sharing

I'm trying to transfer files from a remote win2008 server to my local pc running win7. I have the full GnuWin32 suite installed locally so basic unix utilities are available. Unfortunately, I can't access windows shares between the 2 machines.

I was wondering if there was any "trick" to transfer files between computers with those basic utilities. On the win2008 machine, I have at least telnet.exe and ftp.exe available. I usually use nc for this task, but since nc is unavailable on the server, I was looking for other "creative" ways to do this.

I would like to avoid installing new software on the win7 machine, such as a full blown ftp server. I'm also unable to install new stuff on the server or modify the existing configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can Remote Desktop from one to the other, copy-paste will work for files smaller than 2 GB.